# Saxon: XSLT image processing: cannot convert from xs:string to byte

Tags: xslt, saxon

The following code:

```
<xsl:message>[threfUrl] <xsl:value-of select="$threfUrl" /></xsl:message>
<xsl:variable name="actualHeight" select="itext:getPlainHeight(itext:getInstance($threfUrl))" />
```

throws this error:

```
[xslt] [threfUrl] file:/data/dtemple/share/dita_share/png_debug/screenshot_example.png
[xslt] /tools/dita_ot/1.6/plugins/com.altera.pdf/cfg/fo/xsl/altera_commons.xsl:1124: Fatal Error! Cannot convert from xs:string to byte
```

The PNG file exists and is readable. Using Saxon 9. Namespace: itext="java:com.itextpdf.text.Image"

Any clues as to what is wrong (the error message is not helpful) or how to fix?
Is the "file:/" syntax correct?

Comment: Please share the namespace of that `itext` prefix and the exact version of Saxon you are using. Are you trying to call a Java method? Of which class? How does the signature of the method look like exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Image.html#Image%28java.net.URL%29 try `select="itext:getPlainHeight(itext:new($threfUrl))"`. If that does not work then construct the URL explicitly, as in

```
<xsl:variable name="actualHeight" xmlns:url="java:java.net.URL" select="itext:getPlainHeight(itext:new(url:new($threfUrl)))" />
```

The documentation I cited says

```
 Constructor Detail
Image

public Image(URL url)

    Constructs an Image -object, using an url .

    Parameters:
        url - the URL where the image can be found.
```

so that constructor is public.

Maybe there are different versions of that API, I am not sure why you get an error. Another try might be your original attempt, but passing in a URL, so

```
<xsl:variable name="actualHeight" xmlns:url="java:java.net.URL" select="itext:getPlainHeight(itext:getInstance(url:new($threfUrl)))" />
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for supplying that essential detail! The constructor is protected so itext:new() isn't going to work. The problem with getInstance() is that there are many overloads, eg one expecting a Url and one expecting an Image; and xs:string can't be converted to any. Using url:new() should help (I'm assuming $thefUrl is a string, because we haven't been told otherwise), but resolving the overloaded methods might still be tricky. As to the original error, one of the overloads of getInstance() expects a byte[], and I think it's reporting the error in terms of that particular overload.

Comment: The namespace is xmlns:itext="java:com.itextpdf.text.Image"
Both suggestions throw:
`XPath syntax error at char 41 on line 1122 in {...inHeight(itext:new($threfUr...}:
     [xslt]     Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {java:com.itextpdf.text.Image}new()`

Comment: @Dan, I have edited the answer to try another suggestion, basically your original attempt but passing in URL instead of a string.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know how to solve that at the moment, maybe http://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensibility/functions/choosing-overload helps, or Michael can tell you more.